# Get distinct name, address, max(date) while preserving ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure:

```
ID | fname | lname | street | date
```

I'm trying to grab the distinct fname, lname, street and max(date) but also preserve the id of the matching row.  So there might be multiple lines of matching fname, lname, street but all with different IDs Seems like a simple thing but evidently it's escaped me to this point.

I found some solutions that almost fit this but not quite.  My apologies if this has been covered.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "preserving" the id?  Do you want the id to be a comma-separated list of values in your row?

Comment: Easy way to ask this question - show sample data - show expected results.  Sounds like you need an aliased query that does the following `...(SELECT RecordID, MAX(Date) AS TheMax FROM ... GROUP BY RecordID) t ON t.RecordID = yourTable.RecordID`

Comment: You're asking the database to do to different things... provide a distinct set of records without including the ID as part of the distinction criteria.  And include one thing that makes the records unique.  You have to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fname, lname, street ORDER BY [Date] DESC) RN
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT ID, fname, lname, street, [date]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Wonderful.  Came close to that but thank you very much.  I can sleep now.

Comment: @Dero how does this "preserve the id of the matching row"? Aren't you missing IDs for all rows that match but aren't the max date? Not questioning the validity of the answer, and I'm glad you're happy with it, but it doesn't seem to match with your conflicting requirements (which I think are impossible to meet anyway).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I understood the requirement as needing to have the `ID` of the row with the max date for the same combination of `fname, lname, street`, meaning that you couldn't just group by those columns and obtain the max date. This answer provides that, though I may have misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Assuming max(date) is in the max(id):

```
select max(ID), fname, lname, street, max(date)
from tablename
group by fname, lname, street
```